# Why the next method doesn't change the array but the other one changed its values?

Tags: arrays, methods

the first method doesn't change the array, but the second method changes or swaps the given indexes of the array , why? :

```
    public class Main{
   public static void changeArr1 (int [] arr) { //doesn't do anything?
 int [] tmp = {10, 20}; 
 arr = tmp; 
}
public static void swap(int[] arr,int i,int j){ //swapping 2 array elements?
int temp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j]
arr[j] = temp;
}
}
```

Comment: What code language is this?

Comment: Java @Theshape.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480 helps you.